# array_push() vs. $array[] = .... Which is fastest?

Tags: php, mysql, micro-optimization

I need to add values received from MySQL into an array (PHP). Here is what I've got:

```
$players = array();

while ($homePlayerRow = mysql_fetch_array($homePlayerResult)) {
    $players[] = $homePlayerRow['player_id'];
}
```

Is this the only way of doing it?

**Also**, is the following faster/better?

```
$players = array();

while ($homePlayerRow = mysql_fetch_array($homePlayerResult)) {
    array_push($players, $homePlayerRow['player_id']);
}
```

Comment: If you're only accessing the associative keys (player_id) then it's best to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`. You could also use `mysql_fetch_row` then `$homePlayerRow[0]`, which is slightly faster.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can run it and see that array_push is slower in some cases:

http://snipplr.com/view/759/speed-test-arraypush-vs-array/

Run your code. Enjoy.

Comment: Just tested that link and it's correct, no viagra pointing now. :)

Answer (score 29):

It depends...

> **Documentation says**,
>
> "If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] =  because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function."
>
> Source: https://www.php.net/array_push

So it boils down to how much data you want to cram into that array at any particular moment.

Additionally, there's a fall-back. If the array-referenced doesn't exist when you call it using array_push, you'll bump an error. If you use $array[], the array will be created for you.

Comment: In the end I decided to go with array[] = ... as the array might become very large at some stage

Comment: I believe it's faster to declare an array (with `$arr = array()`) before using `$arr[] = X`. It's also useful if your `$arr[]` statements are inside some control logic - you still have a variable at the end, an array with no elements.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat why is it faster to declare an empty array? Do you have proof of this?