# Add to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [array_push() vs. $array[] = … Which is fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074059/array-push-vs-array-which-is-fastest)

Is it better to use [] or array_push() to add to an array in PHP?

I always use array_push(), but only because it *seems* proper.

```
$array = array();

array_push($array, array('1', '2', '3'));

// or

$array[] = array('1', '2', '3');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074059/array-push-vs-array-which-is-fastest

Comment: its better to use array_push() to add elements in an php array

Comment: See the second answer of the duplicate question. You question is not an *exact duplicate* but that answer is good for this one too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe $array[] is more efficient.

Comment: Turns out thats because i've seen it here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2431629/php-array-push-vs-myarray - do I delete my answer as it's a dup?

Answer (score 0):

When comparing alternative syntax constructs, there are multiple attributes to take into consideration:

- "better"
- faster
- readability

Only one of them is valid.