# PHP While loop with last record?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am creating a website and I need to to some PHP in my jQuery.

My code is as follows;

```
notifications.initMenu({
    2:'#chatPage #tabs #2',
    3:'#chatPage #tabs #3',
    4:'#chatPage #tabs #4',
    5:'#chatPage #tabs #5'
});
```

I want it so that it uses a while loop to echo;

```
$pageID:'#chatPage #tabs #$pageID',
```

And then on the last record echo;

```
$pageID:'#chatPage #tabs #$pageID'
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us the PHP code you have already!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$array = array();
while( ....) {
    $array[] = "\n  $pageID:'#chatPage #tabs #$pageID'";
}
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: just for curiosity, which one is faster, $array[] or array_push()?

Comment: @Simon: Obviously [`$array[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074059/array-push-vs-array-which-is-fastest).

Comment: @Simon: According to a test conducted at the following page (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559844/whats-better-to-use-in-php-array-value-or-array-pusharray-value), assigning variables using $array[] seems to be up to 50% faster than using array_push().

Comment: the manual also mentions that it's faster for one element, which is a bit weird because a good compiler could very easily detect that it's just one element passed and emit the same bytecode, but oh well, php... anyway, this is tipically below the level of the optimisation that you have to worry about

Answer (score 1):

If the comma is what you ask about:

```
for ($i = 2; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "$i:'#chatPage #tabs #$i'" . ($i !== 5 ? "," ? "") . "\n";
}
```