# Push an associate array into another array

Tags: php, wordpress, associative-array

I am trying to do a custom WP_query loop and put the results into an array of associate arrays.. It is not working too well.. I realize the array_push overwrites any arrays that have the same indexes so I have the index increment +1 in the loop so they are not identical..however it still is not working.. My results show correct only on the first index (zero).. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    $permlink='permalink';
    $excerpt='exerpt';
    $title='title';
    $id='id';    
    $finalarray=array();

    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $newitem = array(array(
            'id'.$i =>$id.$i,
            'title'.$i => $title.$i, 
            'excerpt'.$i => $excerpt.$i,
            'permalink'.$i => $permlink.$i 
        ));
        array_push($finalarray, $newitem); 
    }

    $count=0;
    foreach($finalarray as $item){
        echo $count.':'.'<br>';
        echo $item[$count]['title'.$count];
        echo $item[$count]['id'.$count];
        echo $item[$count]['permalink'.$count];
        $count++;
    }

    var_dump($finalarray);
?>
```

Any my results show :

```
0:
title0id0permalink01:
2:
3:
4:
5:
6:
7:
8:
9:
10:
array(11) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id0"]=> string(3) "id0" ["title0"]=> string(6) "title0" ["excerpt0"]=> string(7) "exerpt0" ["permalink0"]=> string(10) "permalink0" } } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id1"]=> string(3) "id1" ["title1"]=> string(6) "title1" ["excerpt1"]=> string(7) "exerpt1" ["permalink1"]=> string(10) "permalink1" } } [2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id2"]=> string(3) "id2" ["title2"]=> string(6) "title2" ["excerpt2"]=> string(7) "exerpt2" ["permalink2"]=> string(10) "permalink2" } } [3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id3"]=> string(3) "id3" ["title3"]=> string(6) "title3" ["excerpt3"]=> string(7) "exerpt3" ["permalink3"]=> string(10) "permalink3" } } [4]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id4"]=> string(3) "id4" ["title4"]=> string(6) "title4" ["excerpt4"]=> string(7) "exerpt4" ["permalink4"]=> string(10) "permalink4" } } [5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id5"]=> string(3) "id5" ["title5"]=> string(6) "title5" ["excerpt5"]=> string(7) "exerpt5" ["permalink5"]=> string(10) "permalink5" } } [6]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id6"]=> string(3) "id6" ["title6"]=> string(6) "title6" ["excerpt6"]=> string(7) "exerpt6" ["permalink6"]=> string(10) "permalink6" } } [7]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id7"]=> string(3) "id7" ["title7"]=> string(6) "title7" ["excerpt7"]=> string(7) "exerpt7" ["permalink7"]=> string(10) "permalink7" } } [8]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id8"]=> string(3) "id8" ["title8"]=> string(6) "title8" ["excerpt8"]=> string(7) "exerpt8" ["permalink8"]=> string(10) "permalink8" } } [9]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id9"]=> string(3) "id9" ["title9"]=> string(6) "title9" ["excerpt9"]=> string(7) "exerpt9" ["permalink9"]=> string(10) "permalink9" } } [10]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id10"]=> string(4) "id10" ["title10"]=> string(7) "title10" ["excerpt10"]=> string(8) "exerpt10" ["permalink10"]=> string(11) "permalink10" } } }
```

So it looks like the values are in the array, however, only the first index ( zero ) prints correctly.. any suggestions? Also, is there any way i can push an associate array and it not be over written so I dont have to increment the index?

Comment: I tried removing array(array()) and replaced with just array(); and now i don't even get index 0 correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $newitem = array(array(
        'id'.$i =>$id.$i,
        'title'.$i => $title.$i, 
        'excerpt'.$i => $excerpt.$i,
        'permalink'.$i => $permlink.$i 
    ));
    array_push($finalarray, $newitem); 
}
```

You are pushing an array, containing an array, containing 4 elements into `$finalarray`.  There is no need for the outer `array()`.  You can just do `$newitem = array(...)`.  `array_push` appends to end of the array, incrementing the index for you.

Second, in your `foreach`, your `$count` variable is not needed at all.  When using `foreach`, `$item` is the element of the array.  No need to look it up by the index.

If you want the index, however, `foreach` can give it to you.

```
foreach($finalarray as $count=>$item){
    echo $count.':'.'<br>';
    echo $item['title'.$count];
    echo $item['id'.$count];
    echo $item['permalink'.$count];
}
```

Your original code wasn't working because in each `$item` there was one array.  That array had one item.  In each element, the inner aray was *always* at index 0.  Incrementing `$count` made it so only the 1st element worked, the others didn't because `$item[1]` didn't exist, it was *always* `$item[0]`.

Comment: this will work for me although it will use WP_query while loop instead of the initial for loop . is there any way to array_push an associate array without using the type of increment on the key..just curious

Comment: @CI_Guy: You could manually add to the array: `$finalarray[$yourkey] = $newitem;`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {
        $newitem = array(array(
            'id'.$i =>$id.$i,
            'title'.$i => $title.$i, 
            'excerpt'.$i => $excerpt.$i,
            'permalink'.$i => $permlink.$i 
        ));
        $finalarray[] = $newitem; 
        unset($newitem);
    }
```

Since you don't care about the key of the final array just add it on using $finalarray[]

Comment: `$finalarray[] = $newitem;` is equivalent to `array_push($finalarray, $newitem);`.

Comment: not entirely correct.  array_push() includes an over head of calling a function there is a previous discussion about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074059/array-push-vs-array-which-is-fastest

Comment: That's the only difference.  One may have a speed increase.  That's it.  They still do *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: they do I never disputed that but usually speed (especially if you're shifting large data sets around) is quite an important factor.