# php foreach loop with continue if value has already been echoed

Tags: php, joomla

I have a foreach loop and I need to add a continue if the value has already been echoed.  I can't find the right syntax.  The loop:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
   echo $result->date . "<br />"; 
}
```

But I need to add in a continue so that if the value has already been echoed, and it comes up again in the loop it gets skipped.  I can't quite get the if/continue statement quite right.

Thoughts, suggestions, ideas?

Comment: Typically you would add the date to an array as you echo each one and if in_array continue.

Comment: Depending on the nature of a single `$result`, `$results = array_unique($results)` before the loop might also help.

Comment: @andy It's an object, you can tell that from the code.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I can see that. However, if the object implements `__toString()` the right way, it would work and result in IMO readable code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @JonathanKuhn in the comments - here is how you would run that loop:

```
$already_echoed = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (!in_array($result->date, $already_echoed)) { //check if current date is in the already_echoed array
        echo $result->date . "<br />";   
    }
    $already_echoed[] = $result->date; //store all dates in an array to check against.
}
```

Comment: Either you forgot to echo the date or implode and echo the array.

Comment: Off topic, is `$array[] = $adding_item` the preferred method of adding to an array? I always use `array_push()`.

Comment: @tatorface `$array[]` preferred - see reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074059/array-push-vs-array-which-is-fastest

Comment: Instead of posting the code here edit your question - it's too difficult to make sense of it in the comment.

Comment: You could try adding `array_unique`: `$dateArr = array_unique(explode('-', $result->date));` which will strip duplicates from the array.  Otherwise it's a bit tough to provide a good answer without seeing the actual data.

Comment: @BradM my answer should work as is if you just swap out `$already_echoed[] = $result->date;` and replace it with `$already_echoed[] = $dateArr[0];`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - got it configured. :)

Comment: @Dan thanks, I did the test on your linked page and it $array[] is by far and away the quicker tool. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dan I'm sorry, but I find your example completely wrong. Here is performance I was talking about http://3v4l.org/Anq56

Answer (score 2):

```
$echoedArray = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (isset($echoedArray[$result->date])) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $result->date . "<br />";
    $echoedArray[$result->date] = true;
}
```

Comment: Be aware. in_array is much slower function rather than check by the key

Comment: in_array is not much slower. And this little difference doesn't really matter. http://3v4l.org/nQZbc

Comment: well, it would matter if you had hundreds thousands of elements

Comment: On HHVM-3.1 in_array() is even faster with 1000 elements. (:

Answer (score 1):

```
    $alreadyOutput = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
       if(in_array($result->date, $alreadyOutput)){
           continue;
       }
       $alreadyOutput[] = $result->date; 
       echo $result->date . "<br />";
    }
```